# Turning off delta faucet after replacement

Tags: plumbing

I have a Delta faucet 1300-1400 series tub faucet. I've replaced the cartridge and when I turn the water on it seems like it blows and I can't turn the water off. I've replaced the cartridge 4 times and the same thing keeps happening. I'm not sure what is wrong.

I'm curious that the brass circle that tighten has anything to do with it moving.

Comment: Did you use the correct cartridge - a Delta OEM replacement. If so - you will need to read the instructions carefully so you understand them. This is not a hard job to do. So 4 units? Turn your main water off first. click this link and read the instructions . https://media.deltafaucet.com/MandI/34459RevA.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace with the same color you had before, either white and blue or grey and white, probably you had the gray one and replaced with the blue.